# Xcode warning - addObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, error-handling

I'm using the following method:

```
-(void) finishQuestionnaire:(id)sender{ 
    NSString * ans;
    NSString* qt = [[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] question] qType];     
    if([qt isEqualToString:@"Slider"]){
        ans = [[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] sliderLabel]text];
    }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"Option"]){               

    }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"TextInput"]){
        ans = [[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] inputAnswer]text];
    }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"ImagePicker"]){

    }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"Comment"]){
        ans = [[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] inputAnswer]text];             
    }
    //UPDATED

NSLog(@"%@", [questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] question]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] question] answer]);

    //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

when qt = comment, I get the following error and the app crashes:

```
 2011-07-20 00:02:04.723 MainMenu[71393:207] -[NSURLCache setAnswer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e29280
    2011-07-20 00:02:04.726 MainMenu[71393:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLCache setAnswer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e29280'
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong....It works when qt is equal to the slider and textinput...

Answer and Question Class

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Answer : NSObject {
    //NSString* answerId;
    NSString* answer;
    NSString* questionId;
    NSString* entryId;
}

//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* answerId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* answer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* questionId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* entryId;

@end


#import "Answer.h"


@implementation Answer

@synthesize answer, questionId, entryId;

@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Answer.h"

@interface Question : NSObject {
    NSString* qId;
    NSString* qTitle;
    NSString* qNumber;  
    NSString* sectionId;
    NSString* qType;
    Answer* answer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* qId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* qTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* qNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* sectionId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* qType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Answer* answer;

@end


@implementation Question
@synthesize qId, qTitle, qNumber, sectionId, qType, answer;

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Initialization code here
        answer = [[Answer alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [answer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Edit: see update code, here is the output:

```
2011-07-20 01:21:04.402 MainMenu[71910:207] <CommentQuestionViewController: 0x4e0b100>
2011-07-20 01:21:04.404 MainMenu[71910:207] <Question: 0x4e55170>
2011-07-20 01:21:04.404 MainMenu[71910:207] (null)
```

Update:

Now I'm not even getting null. My output is just:

```
2011-07-20 01:21:04.402 MainMenu[71910:207] <CommentQuestionViewController: 0x4e0b100>
2011-07-20 01:21:04.404 MainMenu[71910:207] <Question: 0x4e55170>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom type `Answer` does not appear to have a method `setAnswer`.

Make sure that

```
[[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] question] answer];
```

returns an object of type `Answer` (it appears to be of type `NSURLCache`), and then check that the `answer` property of `Answer` has a setter method.

EDIT: To solve this problem without posting your entire source code, start at the beginning and work your way down. By this, I mean answer the following, in order:

1. Of what type is `[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1]`?
2. Of what type is `[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] question]`?
3. Of what type is `[[[questionArray objectAtIndex:currQNum-1] question] answer]`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply. I am trying to access the answer object. Each question object has an answer object inside it. I'll update my post with more code

Comment: @ucabdro: Check out my edit above. Please let me know the three types, in order.

Comment: To help debug, use the `NSStringFromClass()` function: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIIABFJ

Comment: @PengOne - done - Answer is outputting null, possible because it hasn't been set? even so, should it print out null?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `Answer` is a subclass of `NSURLCache`. In your custom subclass header and implementation files, make sure you have defined and written a selector called `-setAnswer:`. Either that, or make sure you are storing an `Answer` instance in `questionArray`, and not an `NSURLCache` instance.

**EDIT**

The following:

```
@implementation Answer

@synthesize answer, questionId, entryId;

@end
```

should be fleshed out. Is this all you have in `Answer.m`?

Comment: I thought using @synthesize automatically creates get/set methods?

Comment: @ucabdro: No, but `@synthesize` does.

Comment: I've used @synthesize so shouldn't setAnswer be valid? Also see class above, Answer subclasses NSObject

Comment: You might follow `PengOne`'s advice to look at the class type of the various levels of `questionArray`. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIIABFJ

Comment: yeah thats all I have in Answer, what needs to be fleshed out? all I need are getters and setters in that class as it is a model.

Comment: Well, at the very least you have a memory leak from retaining properties and not releasing them. What comes back from checking the class types as `PengOne` suggested?

Comment: @ucabdro: From what you write, the problem is most likely that `answ` is **NOT** of type `Answer`. Try following the steps I suggested in the edit to my answer.

Comment: I cannot see the issue. questionArray contains diffent types of questionviewcontrollers. Each questionviewcontroller has a Question pointer. Each Question Object has an Answer pointer.

Comment: Please post `NSLog` results from testing the class type of the three objects that PengOne refers to. What you think may be the correct object types may be something else.

Comment: Also, please post the code that is logging the class types. You might put these statements right before the line `[answ setAnswer:ans];`

Comment: done - code has been update in finishQuestionnaire. Answer is logging as null, possibly because it hasn;t been set, but setAnswer throws the error mentioned above..

Comment: Because you're not getting anything back on the third object, my guess is that you're not really putting the right object in there. Go back further in your code to where you add `Answer` objects to the questionnaire.